# Sticky button below view and on top of keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a button to my forms in my app that is stickied to the bottom of the view regardless of scrolling. How do I get to implement it this feature?

[image: Button at the bottom of the view]

[image: Button on top of the keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to make that view a direct child of your main ViewController's view and position it at the bottom of the view.  That can be done any way that you wish.  Then to move it to "glue" it to the bottom of the view when the keyboard displays or hides you are going to have to listen for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` in `NSNotificationCenter`.  When those events fire you can mimic the animation duration and easing method and move your bottom view up or down by the amount given to you in the willshow and willhide functions.  Something like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;

    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];


    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    //Do whatever you would like to here, likely move your bottom view
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```